# nodejs express mongoose mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I've created a route as a validation all my routes, I want this to handle all my requests and validate them, problem is i want to check if attributes are in the request, not the data just the attributes, lets say the user has an email but the others don't, I want to check if the body has email attribute to run a certain code to validate this email.

how do I know if the

```
req.body.email;
```

is in the body?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
            var record = req.body.record,
                email = record.email,
                phone_number = record.phone_number,
                school_id = req.body.schoolId;

            console.log("validator");

            if (record) {

                if (what is the condition here to check
                    if the body has email)

                    req.asyncValidationErrors()
                    .then(function() {
                        next();

                    }).catch(function(errors) {
                        if (errors) {
                            res.json({
                                status: "error",
                                message: "please make sure your data is correct and your email and phone number are not valid"
                            });
                            return;
                        }
                    });
            });


        module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

To know whether the `email` is in body, You need to check for `undefined`. An attribute which isn't in the body will give you `undefined` when accessed.

```
if (body.email === undefined) {
    console.log('email attribute is not in the body, hence it comes here');
    return res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: "please make sure your data is correct and your email is valid"
    });
}
```

If you've lodash in your app.

```
let _ = require('lodash');

let body = req.body;

if(_.isUndefined(body.email)) {
    console.log('email attribute is not in the body, hence it comes here');
    return res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: "please make sure your data is correct and your email is valid"
    });
}
```

Comment: This will execute the block on all falsy (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values of body.email, not just when it is not there.

Comment: @Florian Yes. You're right. Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated.

Comment: I think lodash is total overkill here, why not (body.email === undefined)? See the source of isUndefined: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L12212

Comment: @DevDig True. I agree with you. but for readability sake, I prefer `lodash`. if I already have it installed in the app, I'll make use of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the npm express-validator to do all your validation on middleware.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator